# Updating a Boolean Field in Django database

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

can i please get an help in what i'm doing wrong? i have a boolean field in which i want when a user clicks on it, it updates in the database, but i can't achieve my aim. my code is below for better understanding
models.py

```py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    designer_size = models.ForeignKey("Frame_Sizes_Designer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)

class Frame_Sizes_Designer(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    small = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

views.py

```py
def DesignerFrameSizeSmall(request):
    dss = get_object_or_404(OrderItem, id=request.POST['id'])
    dss.designer_size.small = not dss.designer_size.small
    dss.save()
    messages.info(request, "Your prefered size has been stored... Thanks")
    return redirect('business:summary')
```

urls.py

```py
app_name = 'business'
urlpatterns =[
    path('designer_frame_small_size/', DesignerFrameSizeSmall, name='dfss')
    ]
```

html and js

```
<form action="" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %} 
              <input type="checkbox" id="designer_small" value="{{dss.designer_size.small}}">
              <label>Small</label>
            </form>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#designer_small').change(function(){
        $.post("{% url 'business:dfss' %}",{
          id: "{{items.id}}",
          designsmall: this.checked,
          csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{csrf_token}}'
        });
        });
```

the error message i get is internal server error when i check my console and i also get an error in my command prompt `dss.designer_size.small = not dss.designer_size.small AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'small'`

Comment: i think it should be "dss.designer_size.save()"

Answer (score 0):

You dss object is missing a value for designer_size i.e. dss.designer_size is None.

Comment: I think the issue is because I'm making use of foreign field i.e ```class OrderItem(models.Model):
    designer_size = models.ForeignKey("Frame_Sizes_Designer", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)```, and I'm trying to get the value of the ```Frame_Sizes_Designer``` which has a foreign key to ```OrderItem```. Without foreign key, it works perfectly fine